# Can not show tables in sequel pro while they do exist according to docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail, sequelpro

I'm rather new at docker and i am currently having some trouble with my new laravel project

I started a new laravel project using laravel sail, which created a mysql container called organiser_mysql_1

I am able to view my database in my docker container, but when i try to use the same credentials on sequel pro, the database does not show.

docker container:

[show databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkAW.png)

Sequel pro:

[sequel pro credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiJqc.png)

[sequel pro error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXeQn.png)

docker ps:

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrutI.png)

env file:

[env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZAbY.png)

database.php

[database.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fkQ7.png)

Command i used to get into docker container:

```
 docker exec -it organiser_mysql_1 mysql -uroot -p
```

I can log into sequel pro without the Database: organiser, but the tables in my docker container are not in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably connecting to to a MySQL server running directly on you host machine (Mac) and not to the one running in your docker container.

**To verify:**

```bash
lsof -i tcp:3306
```

There is a good chance it shows mysqld running on your Mac

**To fix:**

1. Or stop mysqld on your Mac or choose a free port (not 3306) in the next step
2. Map port 3306 in your container to a port on your Mac. You do this by adding `FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307` (or other port) to you .env. This works because of [this line](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/mysql.stub#L4).
3. Restart your containers by running `sail stop && sail up -d`